# Clean way to get near-LIFO behavior from multiprocessing.Queue? (or even just *not* near-FIFO)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Does anyone know a clean way to get near-LIFO or even not near-FIFO (e.g. random) behavior from `multiprocessing.Queue`?

**Alternative Question: Could someone point me to the code for the thread that manages the actual storage structure behind `multiprocessing.Queue`?** It seems like it would be trivial within that to provide approximately LIFO access, but I got lost in the rabbit hole trying to find it.

Notes:

1. I believe `multiprocessing.Queue` [does not guarantee order](http://bugs.python.org/issue4999). Fine. But it is near-FIFO so near-LIFO would be great.
2. I could pull all the current items off the queue and reverse the order before working with them, but I prefer to avoid a kludge if possible.

---

(edit) To clarify: I am doing a CPU bound simulation with `multiprocessing` and so can't use the specialized queues from `Queue`. Since I haven't seen any answers for a few days, I've added the alternative question above.

---

In case it is an issue, below is slight evidence that `multiprocessing.Queue` is near-FIFO. It just shows that in a simple case (a single thread), it is perfectly FIFO on my system:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue

q = mp.Queue()

for i in xrange(1000):
    q.put(i)

deltas = []
while True:
    try:
        value1 = q.get(timeout=0.1)
        value2 = q.get(timeout=0.1)
        deltas.append(value2-value1)
    except Queue.Empty:
        break

#positive deltas would indicate the numbers are coming out in increasing order
min_delta, max_delta = min(deltas), max(deltas)
avg_delta = sum(deltas)/len(deltas)

print "min", min_delta
print "max", max_delta
print "avg", avg_delta
```

prints: min, max, and average are exactly 1 (perfect FIFO)

Comment: Do you only need the LIFO data after all the additions have been made, or do you want a the ability to get the latest data while new values are still being added? If the former, I think reversing the queue's contents is easiest. If you "live" LIFO access you'll probably need to write your own data structure using the shared memory primitives from the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: @Blckknght Yeah if I can wait until everything is there, then it's pretty straightforward (option 2) but it's an ongoing simulation where I want the Queue to act approximately as a stack. I had a quick look at the primitives, hoping to customize the Queue handling thread, but couldn't make heads or tails of it. Investigating that is my next step if I can't find an easy way. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked over the Queue class that lives in `Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py` in my Python installation (Python 2.7, but nothing obvious is different in the version from Python 3.2 that I briefly checked). Here's how I understand it works:

There are two sets of objects that are maintained by the Queue object. One set are multiprocess-safe primatives that are shared by all processes. The others are created and used separately by each process.

The cross-process objects are set up in the `__init__` method:

1. A `Pipe` object, who's two ends are saved as `self._reader` and `self._writer`.
2. A `BoundedSemaphore` object, which counts (and optionally limits) how many objects are in the queue.
3. A `Lock` object for reading the Pipe, and on non-Windows platforms another for writing. (I assume that this is because writing to a pipe is inherently multiprocess-safe on Windows.)

The per-process objects are set up in the `_after_fork` and `_start_thread` methods:

1. A `collections.deque` object used to buffer writes to the Pipe.
2. A `threading.condition` object used to signal when the buffer is not empty.
3. A `threading.Thread` object that does the actual writing. It is created lazily, so it won't exist until at least one write to the Queue has been requested in a given process.
4. Various `Finalize` objects that clean stuff up when the process ends.

A `get` from the queue is pretty simple. You acquire the read lock, decrement the semaphore, and grab an object from the read end of the Pipe.

A `put` is more complicated. It uses multiple threads. The caller to `put` grabs the condition's lock, then adds its object to the buffer and signals the condition before unlocking it. It also increments the semaphore and starts up the writer thread if it isn't running yet.

The writer thread loops forever (until canceled) in the `_feed` method. If the buffer is empty, it waits on the `notempty` condition. Then it takes an item from the buffer, acquires the write lock (if it exists) and writes the item to the Pipe.

---

So, given all of that, can you modify it to get a LIFO queue? It doesn't seem easy. Pipes are inherently FIFO objects, and while the Queue can't guarantee FIFO behavior overall (due to the asynchronous nature of the writes from multiple processes) it is always going to be mostly FIFO.

If you have only a single consumer, you could `get` objects from the queue and add them to your own process-local stack. It would be harder to do a multi-consumer stack, though with shared memory a bounded-size stack wouldn't be too hard. You'd need a lock, a pair of conditions (for blocking/signaling on full and empty states), a shared integer value (for the number of values held) and a shared array of an appropriate type (for the values themselves).

Comment: When I can make time to work on this, I will follow your excellent tour through the mp.Queue and see what I can see. I was hoping the data was held in some object that would be easy to "popleft" but I see it's a pipe as you said. In any case, I guess your explanation here is the best on the internet for how mp.Queue works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [LIFO queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.LifoQueue) in the Queue package (queue in Python 3). This isn't exposed in the multiprocessing or multiprocessing.queues modules.

Replacing your line `q = mp.Queue()` with `q = Queue.LifoQueue()` and running prints: min, max and average as exactly -1.

(Also I think you should always get exactly FIFO/LIFO order when getting items from only one thread.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I am doing a CPU bound simulation that actually uses multiprocessing. To the best of my knowledge, the standard Queue can't handle processes. I'll update my question with some details about that.