# Share a LIFO structure between two Python programs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean way to get near-LIFO behavior from multiprocessing.Queue? (or even just *not* near-FIFO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042575/clean-way-to-get-near-lifo-behavior-from-multiprocessing-queue-or-even-just-n)

I want to share a LIFO (**Queue.LifoQueue()**) structure between two different Python programs.

One will act as **writer** and the other one as **reader**

For now it's just a simple application to share read/write times.

The reader should insert on the LIFO the UNIX timestamp and the reader to read it:

```
**#writer.py**
def getWriteTime():
   os.system("date +%s")
   # write to the LIFO structure



**#reader.py**
def getReadTime():
   # read from the LIFO structure
   # do calculations
```

The question is, how do i share the same Datastructure between two python programs without writing it to the disk?

I know that **multiprocessing** library allows to share resources between processes but i didn't quite get it how to share a LIFO (queue) between to python programs

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of third process to host the shared datastructures. http://redis.io is a popular option.